# Test two clients directly connecting on the same IP and port

Tags: java, sockets

My two clients have to communicate directly with each other. Both of them has `ServerSocket` and `Socket`, too. I can demonstrate it with this code snippet:

```
final ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345);

new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println(clientSocket.getInputStream().read());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();

Socket clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 12345);
clientSocket.getOutputStream().write(1);
clientSocket.getOutputStream().flush();
```

It works OK, but i cannot test them, if they are on the same IP (for example on localhost), because the client will connect to itself. My question is, how can i test or rewrite this, to test two client connecting to each other on the same IP and port?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you have two server sockets?

Comment: Oops, i was in a rush. That's a typo! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the port number configurable via a command line argument, property file or some other way. For the client side you'll need to provide port number of the other instance.